# Nifi add flow file attributes to S3 Object (PutS3Object) Metadata

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I have a simple flow consisting of

GenerateFlowFile ----> PutS3Object ----> Wait

And the generated flow files are getting stored in the bucket correctly.
Now I want to add Metadata to my flow file.

If I add a property "Test1" to PutS3Object, it shows up as "X-Amz-Meta-Test1" in the metadata of the object.

But if I add a property "Test2" in GenerateFlowFile it doesn't show up in metadata.
I tried adding "Test2" as s3.usermetadata.Test2 but it still didn't work.

Is there a way to pass all the flow files attributes as metadata without explicitly adding properties in the PutS3Object.

Comment: What does this mean `But if I add a property "Test2" to PutS3Object in GenerateFlowFile it doesn't show up in metadata.` ?

Comment: It means I add a "Test2" property in GenerateFlow, so it shows up as an attribute in FlowFile for the PutS3Object to read it and put it in the metadata

Comment: Ok that's not how PutS3 works. The Dynamic Property needs to be set on the PutS3Object processor itself, it does not read attributes from the FlowFile and stick it in metadata. See the docs - the only Attribute it reads is `filename` while Dynamic Properties control metadata https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-aws-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.s3.PutS3Object/index.html

Comment: This means if you create `Test2` Attribute on GenerateFlowFile, to get that value into meta data, you would need to add a Dynamic Prperty to PutS3Object of name `test2` and value `${Test2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PutS3Object](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-aws-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.s3.PutS3Object/index.html) only inserts metadata values that you have set as Dynamic Properties on the PutS3Object processor itself. Please see the docs link and look at the Dynamic Properties section.

PutS3Object does not just stick *any* Attribute you set as metadata, otherwise you would end up with potentially hundreds of metadata entries that you aren't interested in. The only Attribute it reads by default is `filename` - please see the Reads Attributes section of the docs.

If you have an existing Attibute, and you want to push the value of this Attribute into the metadata, you must add a Dynamic Property to PutS3Object and reference the value of the Attribute.

E.g. you have an Attribute called `file_author` with a value `Steve` and you want the S3 object to have the metadata field `author` with the value `Steve`:

You would add a Dynamic Property to PutS3Object with a name of `author` and a value of `${file_author}`.

Edit:
You *could* fork PutS3Object into a custom processor to add the dynamic functionality you want, but I would recommend just using the standard PutS3Object config and manually configuring the Attributes you want.

Comment: I want to add the all the attributes of my generated flow file to the metadata, without adding dynamic properties manually. Is there a way to make all attributes as key:value pairs and then add that dictionary as dynamic property ?

Comment: No I don't think there's any way to do that

Comment: Can custom processor be a solution here ?

Comment: Sure, you could fork the PutS3Object into a custom processor to achieve this. But I'm not sure how writing a new processor is less effort that listing a few Attribute names in PutS3 config.